# Custom datetime formating Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, formatting, format

I want to create custom format date and i'm struggling with that, need help.
Is it possible to create datetime format like this "02FEB2021 00:00:00" in Python ?

Comment: use `datetime_object.strftime('%d%b%Y %H:%M:%S').upper()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes with a [custom formatter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes)

```
from datetime import datetime

fmt = "%d%b%Y %H:%M:%S"

date_str = datetime.now().strftime(fmt).upper()
print(date_str)  # 04NOV2021 19:07:50

date = datetime.strptime(date_str, fmt)
print(date)  # 2021-11-04 19:07:50
```

Comment: .upper() fix problem, thanks!